# Searching for all keywords with foreach and adding to the url

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to do my function to look up each added keyword in the search text area.

Here is the function

```
$search = $request->input('search');

foreach(explode("\r\n", $search) as $lines) {
         
   $resource = Http::get("http://localhost:4000/keys/$lines");
        
}

return view('search', compact('resource'));
```

and the form

```
<form id="form-buscar" action="{{ route('search') }}" method="POST">
{{ csrf_field() }}
     <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="form-control" type="textarea" name="search" required></textarea>
                    
        <div class="submit">
            <button class="btn btn-success pull-right" type="submit">Search</button>
        </div>
     </div>
</form>
```

Simple input on the textarea

```
keyword
keyword1
keyword2
```

Currently, it gets/shows results only for the last word. What is my mistake here?

Comment: It is laravel. I didn't include it because I believe that this has nothing to do with laravel and it is pure php side.

Comment: @RiggsFolly without knowing the delimiter for the value generated for `$resource` wouldn't it be better to build `$resource` as an array?

Comment: @Martin Yup that would be a much better idea.

Comment: _NOTE_ Be careful using `"\r\n"` for a line ending. Thats Windows way, but linux uses `"\r"`

Comment: the name `$lines` can be a source of mistakes here, in this variable will be stored each line separately through the iteration, `$line` would be better. BTW we should know how `http://localhost:4000/keys/` can receive multiple parameters to be able to answer you (coma separated? a raw array?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$resource` inside the foreach is only running for each iteration (each iteration is not aware of any other iteration), you want to view all the iterations so you need to append them inside the foreach and then run the final full listing outside of the foreach. You could probably use an `array_walk()` function.

Therefore; build an array of results and then cycle the `Http::get` request for each value in the array, before returning that result as a sum off all child array values:

## Example

```
$search = $request->input('search');
// This replaces the foreach loop 
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $search); 
array_walk($lines, function(&$value){ 
     $value = Http::get("http://localhost:4000/keys/".$value);
   });
return view('search', ($lines?:[]));
```

This applies the custom anonymous function which returns the `Http::get` result, to each element in the array.

NOTE: as pointed out by RiggsFolly, `\r\n` is not quite universal for PHP line endings so using PHP_EOL is a system-aware/safe workaround to use instead.

Comment: wouldn't this version append the search results of each keyword separately instead of doing a single search for all the keywords?

Comment: @Kaddath why? It updates the keyword values in the array with the correspondng `Http::get` result for each value already there.  Each keyword has one search function as per the original code.

Comment: I know I am being pickie, but as the PHP does not know the users OS, I am not sure using `PHP_EOL` is going to work universally either, as it uses the servers OS to work out the line ending to use. I was going to suggest that too, but now I cannot think of a good solution for this

Comment: @RiggsFolly if you're not sure you can still use `preg_split`. You are probably right about my first comment, I thought the `get` was to retreive the search results

Comment: @Kaddath Ahh regex, I try and avoid those, but that might be the best solution

Comment: @RiggsFolly how about exploding on simply `\n` which is more universal than the combi of both `\r\n` ? I've never found an issue with using PHP_EOL but I only use Linux based systems, because, life's too short for windows.... The only use of `\r` is legacy mac which is highly unlikely to be a server now, fingers crossed.

Comment: @Kaddath regex is really processor intensive for such a minor thing this is an overkill for a very, very tiny edgecase. Use `\n` as the line break but as I say, I've never had a problem with PHP_EOL but this is all down to what the OP feels is best for their setup.

Comment: @Martin that could be considered as a far too premature optimization here, to split a list of keywords from a request param there will be no difference. I've used regex to create code parsers that work on file with thousands of lines without any problems, on laptops that are not particularly powerful

Comment: Thanks, @Martin but there is something wrong that I can't see it. 1. it still returns only the last keyword. If I `var_dump($value)` I see too empty strings + one that is not empty(the last one). 2. When I try to use the `$value` outside the array_walk it gives me an undefined variable.

Comment: @Jake outside of array_walk the value you should be referencing is `$lines` not `value`.

Comment: @Jake sorry I forgot the `&` on the function, fixed my code now. this should work; please see here for a basic example: https://onlinephp.io/c/fe910

Comment: Hm, got `Call to a member function body() on array` when I try `foreach(explode(', ', $lines->body()) as $line)`. Those were worked prior to the array walk function. $lines->body have values of `keyword,3`, `keyword1,3124`, and so on.

Comment: array_walk *replaces* the foreach in your original code.

Comment: This is another foreach after the array_walk ... when I got the result and want to foreach it

Comment: @Jake that is out of the scope of this question. Your original code ends up with an array generated by `compact` function. I give you an array generated by the `array_walk` function. If there's a problem that the data is an array that's an additional to anything asked in this question so far. `:-)`

Comment: You're right. Sorry about that. Your solution is working. Will try to fix the other issue now. Thanks!

Comment: @Jake I have added a qualifier so that if for whatever reason the end value ($lines/$resource) is empty, then it is converted to an empty array so it maintains the expected data type (array).

Comment: @Jake no worries at all. Error cascades are always annoying. Feel free to search and ask another Q if you can't find the workaround for it.